# Understanding about Rails 3 Mini MagicK Validation failed?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

**ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in ProfilesController#upload_image**

```
Validation failed: Avatar Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: Command ("gm identify -ping -quiet
-format "%w %hn" "/tmp/mini_magick20130215-9791-f87uvk.jpg"") failed: {:status_code=>1, :output=>"gm identify: Unrecognized option (-quiet).\n"}
```

will be shown while uploading an image

even the image present and all the directory are available but i dont know why this happens?

anyone explain how to clear this Validation failed error.

my gem version

```
mini_magick 3.4
```

Thanks in advance.